# Wanting to change colour of my pen in java

Tags: java, colors

I have created an Etch A Sketch sort of program using Java. Now I am wanting to change the colour of the shapes and lines that I draw. I am struggling with how to do this. This is as far as I have got at the moment Any help would be mostly appreciated.

```
        else if (String1.equalsIgnoreCase("red"))
        {

            set.PenColor(Color.RED);    

        }
```

With this code I get the;
    set. cannot be resolved AND
    the method setColor is undefined
Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you expect us to answer this without seeing the rest of your code?

Comment: Before you vote to close, calm down and give this guy time to clarify his question.

Comment: What is 'set' supposed to be and you do you plan to access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using plain awt - Graphics class has a method (setColor) to set the color to be used.

[JavaDoc for Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#setColor%28java.awt.Color%29).

This graphics object should be used in paint methods then.